# Eliminating Unnecessary Vertices In a Graph

Tags: graph-algorithm

I am studying for an interview and came across this question which I am having trouble solving. It goes like this:

Create an efficient algorithm that does two tasks to an undirected graph G: (1) elim- inates multiple copies of edges by replacing them with a single edge and (2) replaces edges (u, v) and (v,w) by an edge (u,w) where v is an edge of degree two. Be aware that removing a vertex with degree two can create multiple copies of edges and that removing multiple copies of edges can create a vertex with degree two.

I don't quite understand how removing a vertex with degree two can create multiple copies of edges and how removing multiple copies of edges can create a vertex with degree two. Can someone help clarify?

Answer (score 0):

in a graph of four vertexes, w, x, y, z

```
  w *-----  x  -----* y ------- z 
    |               |
    *---------------*
```

if you replace (w, x) and (x, y) with (w, y) using replaces rule, than it looks like, there are two parallel edges from w to y.  if you remove duplicate edges, than the graph, will look like:

```
  w --------------- y ------- z
```

so now if you replace (w, y) and (y, z)  with (w, z) we are down to just (w, z)

```
  w ------------------------- z
```

not exactly what was intended

Answer (score 0):

Removing a vertex with degree two can create multiple copies of edges:

original edge: (u,v), (v,w), (u,w)   after removing v: (u, w), (u, w)

Removing multiple copies of edges can create a vertex with degree two:

original edge: (u,v), (v,w), (v,w)   after removing (v,w): (u, v), (v, w)